# Problem in giving input to JTable from keyboard

Tags: java, swing

I want to know how to give input to the cell in a jtable from keyboard.

And when I try to do this when I move on to next cell the previous enter data is removed or erased automatically.

I am using abstracttable model for creating jtable.

Comment: if you give your code here, you can get more precise solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> iam using abstracttable model for creating jtable....
>
> and when i try to do dis when i move on to next cell the previous enter data is removed or erased automatically....

The AbstractTableModel doesn't implement the setValueAt(...) method. So unless your custom model implements this correctly you will lose the data entered in the editor.

I suggest you keep it simple and use the DefaultTableModel until you better understand how a JTable works. The code would be:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(...);
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in [*How to Use Tables*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), you can specify a renderer and editor for each column in a `JTable`, or you can override `getColumnClass()` to obtain the default for any of the listed data types. In addition, you might compare what you're doing with one of the [examples](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg) listed there or edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are not saving the data entered into your model.  Secondly, I would suggest extending DefaultTableModel instead of AbstractTableModel unless you have a good reason.